# ATG - Error at startup adding new .jar file

Tags: slf4j, atg

How can we resolve this issue? Please let me know if I have to make some jar version changes.

Error from Console:

```
13:21:02,220 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
13:21:02,221 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Found binding in [vfszip:/C:/XXXX-atg/jboss-eap-5.1/jboss-as/common/lib/slf4j-jboss-logging.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
13:21:02,221 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/express-atg/ATG/ATG10.1.1/DAS/lib/slf4j-jdk14-1.5.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
13:21:02,221 ERROR [STDERR] SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
13:21:02,869 INFO  [RoutingSearchService] Initializing cache for environment "ATGProfile"
13:21:02,903 INFO  [RoutingSearchService] Initializing cache for environment "ATGProfileBulk"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you added two different implementations of the SLF4J to your classpath:
The errormessage already gives a hint what to do in this situation:
http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings